# Regex Replace all found occurrences if the word not matches with the given prefix

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

How can I replace text value without matching given prefix of text??

**For Example:**

`test hello world... I know hello world, this seems hello world..`

then our replace value is "HI"

the text will be..

`test hello world... I know HI, this seems HI..`

Comment: You mean when the word 'test' isn't before 'hello world'?

Comment: so what you mean you want to replace hello world in string with hi

Comment: If a word test before hello world is found, there will be no replacing process. but if not found, hello world will be replace with HI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!test\s)\bhello world\b
```

This assumes that you're interested in test when it proceeds directly.

Answer (score 0):

to be somewhat clever and to avoid regular expression you might do something like this

```
string v = s.Replace("hello world", "HI"); //replace hello world in all occurrences with HI 

string newstring  = v.Replace("test HI", "hello world"); //place hello world where hi is after test
```